# Showing $\left(rR'\right)'+\lambda rR=0$ has a trivial solution when $\lambda=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I am trying to show that the ODE, 
>   $$\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)+\lambda rR=0$$ has a trivial solution when $\lambda=0$. The boundary conditions are $R(b)=0$ (radius $r=b$) and $R'(0)=0$.

I thought that if $\lambda=0$, then $$\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dR}{dr}\right)=0\implies rR''+R'=0\implies r^2R''+rR'=0.$$ 
This is a Cauchy-Euler equation. Letting $R=r^a$, the solution of this equation is $$R(r)=A+B, \ \ A,B\in\mathbb{R}.$$
However, the boundary conditions do not imply that this is a trivial solution?

Comment: When you look for solutions in the form $R(r)=r^{\alpha}$ you get a double $\alpha=0$, so you are in the case where, to find an independent solution, you need logarithmic factors. One of your solutions is a constant, the other one is $C\log r$. You should be able to eliminate the singular part from your conditions at $r=0$ and then adjust the other constant.

Comment: Are we assuming that $R$ must be finite as $r\rightarrow 0^+$? I'm just wondering how we deal with the boundary condition $R'(0)=0$. If $R'(0)=0$, then $$R'(r)=\frac{C}{r}, \ r\rightarrow 0.$$ Does this mean $C=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac d {dr} (r \frac {dR} {dr})=0$ implies that $r \frac {dR} {dr}$ is a constant $c$. Hence $\frac {dR} {dr} =c/r$ and $R= c\ln\, r+c'$. You should now be able to use the boundary conditions to show that $R=0$.

Comment: Are we assuming $R$ is finite as $r\rightarrow 0^+$?

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney For $R$ to remain finite as $r \to 0^{+}$, you would require $c = 0$. Can you see how this relates to showing your original DE only has trivial solutions if $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: I believe so. Thanks a lot.